# Kill fragment in navigation controller

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, fragment, navigationcontroller

My flow of fragment is like this

```
Main -> A -> B -> C ->A
```

In fragment c, it has a submit button which will return to A. 
When I press back button in A, I want it back to Main. But it return to fragment c instead.

In fragment C, I use this

```
 findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_c_to_a)
```

**nav_graph.xml**

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentC"
        android:name="xxx"
        android:label="xxx">
        <action
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/fragmentA"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"
            android:id="@+id/action_c_to_a"
            app:destination="@id/fragmentA" />
    </fragment>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have `A` in your stack, when you navigate to it? Your configuration is correctly setup and works as you want it to.

Comment: I understand what you want to do. But you should implement "Up" navigation, not "Back" in this case. User should be expecting back as back, not back as up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not pop up to fragment A? You could just call `findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.fragmentA, false)` instead of navigating with an action.

Comment: not working val action = CheckoutFragmentDirections.actionCheckoutFragmentToProductFragment()
        findNavController().navigate(action)

Answer (score 0):

try to look at my complete solution with removing/killing fragment from backstack.

[Navigation Component set transition animation programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51856988/navigation-component-set-transition-animation-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the back button behavior to do this.
[Provide custom back navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to set a `app:popUpTo` without setting `app:destination`. Indeed, setting a `app:destination` will create a fragment and add it to the backstack which is not what you want.

To you can just remove :

```
app:destination="@id/fragmentA"
```

If you have this :

```
app:popUpTo="@+id/fragmentA"
```

And it will really pop the backstack until **fragmentA**